# Vectorizing a function in Python using Numpy einsum

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, vectorization

I'm trying to use Numpy to vectorize a function for calculating the *average marginal effects* of the features in a multinomial logit model fitted using scikit-learn. I have managed to do the calculations using *for loops*, which looks like this

```
#Get probabilities for each obs i belonging to class j. shape =  N * J
probas = fitted_model.predict_proba(X)
#Get coefficients. Shape j_classes * k_coefficients
betas = fitted_model.coef_

J = probas.shape[1]
N = probas.shape[0]
K = betas.shape[1]

avg_margins = np.zeros([K, J])
        
for j in tqdm(range(J)):
    for k in range(K):
        dydw = 0
        for i in range(N):
            dydw += probas[i,j] * (betas[j,k] - np.dot(probas[i,:],betas[:,k]))
        avg_margins[k,j] = 1 / N * dydw
```

However, this is very slow, why I want someway of getting rid of the loops. I'm a beginner with both Numpy and linear algebra so please bare with me, but I think my best bet is using `numpy einsum` and where I've gotten so far is this

```
avg_margins = 1 / N * np.einsum('ij, jk -> kj', probas,  betas - np.einsum('im, mk -> k', probas, betas))
```

This unfortunately returns the wrong results and I'm unsure where I'm going wrong. Any help or hints of where I'm going wrong would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, but what is `tqdm`?

Comment: First of all sorry, for clarity I should've removed that from the code snippet. Tqdm is a progress bar that simply estimates the time it will take to run your loop. Can be very helpful for scraping or other things that might take a long time: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, thank you. I guess your question is already answered though.

Answer (score 0):

No einsum is needed here:

```
diff = betas[:,None] - np.dot(probas, betas)
avg_margins = np.sum(probas * diff.T, axis=1) / N
```